# Adding row number to each row of my output - I gave up(Not a python pro)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
counter = 1
numbers = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 99: "))
column = int(input("How many columns would you like? "))
output_string = ""

col_counter = 0
while (counter <= numbers):
    output_string += str(counter)+" "
    counter += 1
    col_counter += 1
    if(col_counter == column):
       print(output_string)
       output_string=""
       col_counter = 0
print(output_string)
```

How would I add row numbers to this code? My code is just the way I want... Just want the output to be

Row 1: 12345

Row 2: 678910

Row 3: 11121314

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: like 50, any input is fine. Just want whatever the input is, and column... eg 55 with 5 columns, it will be row1: 12345 row2: 678910

Comment: Your code could be more pythonic by using `for counter in range(numbers)` and removing the parens around the while/if conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a variable to represent the row number and make the print like this:

```
counter = 1
numbers = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 99: "))
column = int(input("How many columns would you like? "))
output_string = ""
row = 1
col_counter = 0
while (counter <= numbers):
    output_string += str(counter)+" "
    counter += 1
    col_counter += 1
    if(col_counter == column):
       print('Row'+str(row)+':'+output_string)
       output_string=""
       col_counter = 0
       row+=1
print(output_string)
```

**UPDATE**:
I missed that the last line is not resulting the correct output in case your numbers are not equally divisible.So, change the last line to be like this:

```
if output_string != '':
  print('Row'+str(row)+':'+output_string)
```